# why std::thread can be returned with not copyable limitation?

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, stdthread

I'm quite confused about the successful compilation of the code below. The variable 't' in the function 'g' is obviously a left-value. When 'g' returns to the main function, 't' should be copied. However, the thread object is not copyable, so why does it compile successfully?

```
#include <thread>

void some_other_function(int) {
    return;
}
std::thread g()
{
    std::thread t(some_other_function,42);
    return t;
}

int main() {
    g();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `return` a local variable, the move constructor will be used instead of the copy constructor (if available). While `std::thread` does not have a copy constructor, it does have a move constructor so this will work.

See [Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters)

It's also possible that the compiler will elide the move completely due to NRVO (named return value optimization), but this isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain their downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

The code compiles because of [Named Return Value Optimization (NRVO)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), or the [implicit move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters) that takes place if it cannot be performed. Regardless of which happens, the copy constructor won't be used.

This technique is possible whenever you return a local variable by name, like:

```cpp
return t;
```

in your example.
It is possible to treat the local object `t` as if it was the returned object outside of the function, so no move or copy constructor is called.
As said above, if NRVO cannot be performed by the compiler, the move constructor is a fallback.
`std::thread` is non-copyable, but movable, so this code works.

*Note: your code would fail to compile for classes that are neither copyable nor movable, like `std::mutex`.*

Comment: NRVO is not guaranteed (even in C++17). Only return of a prvalue is guaranteed to be optimized.

Comment: @interjay did you even read the answer? I said "if NRVO cannot be performed", so it should be obvious that it's an optional optimization.

Comment: You said "This code compiles because of NRVO" which is wrong.

Comment: @interjay part of NRVO is using an implicit move as a fallback when the optimization isn't possible. Of course you can split hairs and say that it's two totally separate things, but one motivates the other.

Comment: Saying that it compiles because of an optional compiler optimization is misleading.

Comment: @interjay anyhow, I have rephrased the answer to emphasize that the implicit move is crucial for this code to be well-formed. I agree that it's misleading, but `return t;` being an implicit move when `t` is an lvalue is also counter-intuitive. I think understanding NRVO as a motivating factor is very helpful. Also, no move constructor will be used if NRVO is possible, so it somewhat takes precedence.